# what is difference between useCallback and useMemo in react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

can you tell me. what is difference between `useCallback()` and `useMemo()` in react hooks and when is the function used or what are the examples?

Comment: `useCallback` is a shortcut for a common kind of memoization.  `useCallback((foo) => bar)` is the same as `useMemo(() => (foo) => bar)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**useMemo:**

A hook used to memorize a **value**, when certain values of the dependency array change.

Instead, useCallback memorizes a function, a **callback**, so when the component re-renders, you don't have to recompute the whole function.

**UseMemo sample use:**

For example, you want to calculate the total of the cart payment. I'll memorize that total value, and only change it when the taxes percent changes too.

```
const total = useMemo(() => taxes + subtotal, [taxes]);
```

**UseCallBack sample use:**

I want to perform various calls to an API, or a DB to search for certain values (e.g, on a searchbar), but I don't want the component to recompute the function every time it renders, so I memorize the function:

```
const getCharacters = useCallback(() => {
      if(input.trim() !== ""){
        const value = input.toLocaleLowerCase()
        const chars = Characters.filter((character)  => {
          return character.name.toLowerCase().includes(value)}
        )
        setCharacters(chars)
      }else {
        setCharacters([])
      }
  }, [input]);
```

*Usually, useCallback is used when a useEffect hook is also needed, to mount an element when certain dependency changes:*

```
useEffect(() => {
   getCharacters()
  }, [input, getCharacters]);
```